# How to iterate over all columns in a table using Snowflake Javascript Stored Procedure or Function?

Tags: javascript, sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in Snowflake with 100+ columns and I am trying to get a count of all distinct values in each column and ultimately concatenate all of the counts for each column into one table. If I were to do it on just one column it would be something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "AGE", count(*) AS "Frequency"
FROM 
    db.schema.tablename
WHERE 
    "SURVEYDATE" < "2019-07-29"
GROUP BY
    AGE;
```

I know this would be somewhat trivial to do in Python (perhaps I should just do it in PySpark, I'm open to recommendations), but for what I think would be ease of use for both my team and faster to do on 300 million rows, I would like to use the Snowflake Javascript procedural language to do something like:

```
create or replace procedure column_counts(table)
returns array
language javascript
as
$$
var num_columns = //get number of columns
var columns = [list of columns]
var results_array = [];

for (i = 0; i < num_columns; i++) {
    var col_count = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: 'SELECT DISTINCT columns[i], count(*) AS "Frequency" FROM 
    db.schema.tablename WHERE "SURVEYDATE" < "2019-07-29" GROUP BY columns[i]' }).execute(); //This returns a table of all distinct values in that column and their counts
    results_array.push([columns[i], col_count]) //I then want an array like [column_name[0...i], distinct_value[0....n], frequency]
    return results_array;
$$
;
CALL column_counts();
```

I am still pretty new to using this procedural language in Snowflake and Snowflake as a whole, so definitely open to recommendations on how to do this best and in a repeatable manner for new tables that come in each month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible without any kind of procedural code. For instance by using JSON:

```
WITH cte AS ( -- here goes the table/query/view
  SELECT TOP 100 OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*) AS json_payload
  FROM SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.ORDERS
)
SELECT f.KEY, 
      COUNT(DISTINCT f."VALUE") AS frequency, 
      LISTAGG(DISTINCT  f."VALUE" ,',') AS distinct_values  -- debug
FROM cte
, LATERAL FLATTEN (input => json_payload) f
-- WHERE f.KEY IN ('column_name1', 'column_name2', ...) -- only specific columns
GROUP BY f.KEY;
```

Output:

```
+-----------------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+
|       KEY       | FREQUENCY |                DISTINCT_VALUES                 |
+-----------------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+
| O_ORDERPRIORITY |         5 | 2-HIGH,1-URGENT,5-LOW,4-NOT SPECIFIED,3-MEDIUM |
| O_ORDERSTATUS   |         3 | P,O,F                                          |
| O_SHIPPRIORITY  |         1 | 0                                              |
| ...             |       ... | ....                                           |
+-----------------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+
```

How it works:

1. Generate JSON per each row using `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*)`
2. Flatten JSON to key/value
3. Group by key and apply specific aggregation function `COUNT/COUNT(DISTINCT )/LISTAGG/MIN/MAX/...`

---

Version that provides distribution per each column/value:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT TOP 100 OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*) AS json_payload
  FROM SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.ORDERS
)
SELECT f.KEY, f."VALUE", COUNT(*) AS frequency
FROM cte
, LATERAL FLATTEN (input => json_payload) f
-- WHERE f.KEY IN ('column_name1', 'column_name2', ...) -- only specific columns
GROUP BY f.KEY, f."VALUE"
ORDER BY f.KEY, f."VALUE";
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I had no idea about how to use cte and I feel like my eyes have been opened. I'm guessing that I can make the query as complicated as I want and specific certain sets of columns as well with IFF statements or the like and I won't have any issues?

Comment: If I wanted to do 70 of the 100 columns how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @kwarner You could think about CTE as of nicer way of using subqueries(they have other qualities too). So you could perform any kind of transformation you like in cte and materialize it as JSON later. As for limiting column you could do it using `WHERE f.KEY IN ('col1', 'col2', ...)` or `WHERE f.KEY LIKE 'colprefix%'`(if they have common pattern)

Comment: Thank you for all the helpful information. One last question, if I wanted to take a percentage like COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) how would I prevent ID from being an invalid identifier in this context?

Comment: @kwarner This should be *a new question* with sample data and desired resultset. Anyway maybe sth like: COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN f.KEY = 'ID' THEN f."VALUE" END) will do